# Is there any Way to Hide controls in Design view

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, panel

My program includes many panels and controls in a same form.. Therefore i have some trouble when I need to edit them.
Is there any way to hide them in design view (visual studio 2015 C#)
Thanks

Comment: Please provide some more info, maybe a screenshot

Comment: Sounds like you have a load of overlapping controls and are showing/hiding them at runtime. That's usually a sign of an incorrect design; for example, perhaps you should be using a tab control (with the tabs hidden at runtime) or some other kind of container control.

Comment: I have 2 forms in my program.. And one of them contains 4 panels and each panel includes so many controllers (text boxes, buttons.... Etc)  so when i need to edit my first panel its very hard to do that.. (overlapping 4 panels.. you are right bro)
Is there any way to fix it or i would be much obliged if you could give me a solution for that i do not need to add more forms to my program that's why I used to use panels.. Thank you.. hope you'll understand and give me a solution

Comment: You'll probably be happier if you make each panel a UserControl, then you can lay each one out independently.  A UserControl gives you the same experience as designing separate forms, but as runtime you get panels not separate windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Friend